# How to increase PHP Limits in phpMyAdmin using Xampp server?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, demo

I'm getting this error message when I import demo in Wordpress.

> Demo import failed.Please check for PHP limits in red on the System
>   Status page. Change those to the recommended values and try again.

```
post_max_size = 4096M 
upload_max_filesize = 4096M 
max_execution_time = 3000 
max_input_vars = 3000 
memory_limit = 512M
```

I have changed values into the php.ini file but still getting this message.

Comment: did you restart services?

Comment: yes i have restarted.

Comment: what demo are you trying to import? It seems very extensive memory limit.

Comment: I was trying to import Avada university demo in nulled Avada theme.

Comment: Yes the limits are far above those required for the theme https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/technical/what-to-do-if-xml-import-fails/

Comment: also you must have WP debug disabled

Comment: do we not set limits above the required?

Comment: WP debug is already disabled but demo is not importing.